# To Handle Popup message in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click OK button on the popup window with the below selenium Webdriver code

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

but i am geeting the Bellow error

org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: No alert is present (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.22 seconds
Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 20:21:45'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 2003', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.2', java.version: '1.6.0_21'
Session ID: ddceb914-d74e-44c4-a159-9f1f591e7be1
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

here is the screenshot of the window

[image: PopUpMessage]

Comment: Can you provide the URL of this web-page?

Comment: Are you sure that is a pop up? Or an overlay which looks like pop up?

Comment: are you sure that this is a popup? It more looks like a popup window, try using driver.switchTo().window("handle"); instead of Alert().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a window and not an alert. Try following code:

```
String winHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); //Get current window handle.
for(String windowsHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
     driver.switchTo().window(windowsHandle); //Iterate to the new window handle.
}
/*
Do any action on window or just close it.
*/
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); //Switch to original window.
```